# how to get multiple values from selected - asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

How can I get chosen values from `select` tag after click button? Here I get html `select` with multiple choose. 
`selTest.Value` returns only first selected item.

```
    <select runat="server" id="selTest" name="selTest" data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chzn-select" style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
      <option value=""></option> 
      <option value="United States" selected="selected">United States</option> 
      <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option> 
      <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option> 
      <option value="Zambia" selected="selected">Zambia</option> 
      <option value="Zimbabwe" selected="selected">Zimbabwe</option>
    </select>

   <asp:Button ID="testBt" runat="server" OnClick="testBt_Click" Text="ds" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void testBt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Loop through the items in select and look at the property selected.

Comment: Your list doesn't allow for multiple selection, you need to specify `multiple` for that; but anyway, why not use a .NET control proper, like ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

If you use an ASP.NET ListBox proper you can access the `Items`, strongly-typed, and query:

```
<asp:ListBox runat="server" id="MyList" SelectionMode="Multiple">
  <asp:ListItem Value="-1"></asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Valuealue="United States" Selected="True">United States</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Valuealue="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Valuealue="Yemen">Yemen</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Valuealue="Zambia" Selected="True">Zambia</asp:ListItem> 
  <asp:ListItem Valuealue="Zimbabwe" Selected="True">Zimbabwe</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

And then to get the selected items (using Linq):

```
var selected = MyList.Items.Where(i => i.Selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="Options" SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server">
  <asp:ListItem Value="option1" >Option #1</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="option2" >Option #2</asp:ListItem>
  <asp:ListItem Value="option3" >Option #3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
    var options = Options.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
                  .Where(item => item.Selected)
                  .Select(item => item.Value)
                  .ToList();
```

'options' will be a list of string contains all selected values.